# Is $\sqrt{-x^2-\frac{1}{x}}$ a rational function?

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-functions

I have to construct a rational function with the range being $[-1,0)$, which is pretty much just $-1$. I came up with the solution $\sqrt{-x^2-\frac{1}{x}}$. It works for the range, but I'm not sure if it is a rational function.

Comment: A rational function $g$ is any function which can be represented as $g(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $p,q$ are two polynomial functions.

Comment: See if that happens for the function you found.

Comment: This seems to have _domain_ $[-1,0)$, but _range_ $[0,\infty)$. [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efmkgsvzn1)

Comment: In any case: $f(x)$ is supposed to have range $[-1,0)$. If $f(x)$ is rational, so is $\dfrac1{f(x)}$. What's _it's_ range? I would think it's $(-\infty,-1]$. (Why? Think about this!) What about $1+\dfrac1{f(x)}$? I would think it's $(-\infty,0]$. What about $-1-\dfrac1{f(x)}$? I would think it's $[0,\infty)$. Do you know any rational function (polynomials are also rational) with range $[0,\infty)$? If so, you can just work backwards to get $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply no. A rational function cannot have a square root in their numerator (the denominator of yours is 1). Since your function $$f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2 - \frac 1x}$$ has a radical, the function isn't rational (because square roots are not polynomials, so functions with roots are not rational).

### Edit:

The term inside the radical isn't a perfect square anyways, since for any value of $x$, $-x^2 - \frac 1x$ will **never** be a perfect square, even for your range of values. Especially for the fact where $x = 0$ because $\sqrt{-(0)^2 - \frac 10}$ cannot be a real root (because the $\frac 10$ part is indeterminate). I credit the commenter of this post for the edit.

Comment: It's not good enough just to say there can't be a square root. The term inside the square root needs not to be a perfect square.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your function
$f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2 - \frac 1x}
$
is *not* rational.

For one thing,
it is imaginary for
$x \gt 0$
and for
$x < -1$.

One way to prove 
that $f$ is not rational
is to note that
a rational function
must behave like
$x^k$ as $x \to \infty$
and as $x \to 0$,
where $k$ is an integer
($0$, positive, or negative).

If$-1 < x < 0$,
$f(x)
=\frac1{\sqrt{-x}}\sqrt{x^3+1}
\approx\frac1{\sqrt{-x}}(1+\frac{x^3}{2})
$
as
$x \to 0^-$.

However,
$f(x)
\approx x^{-1/2}
$
as
$x \to 0^-$,
which is not of the form
$x^k$.